Bent valve from timing belt failure
I just bought a 2012 VW Jetta with the 2.0L gas engine. The kid I bought it from apparently never did any maintenance. 150K on original timing belt before it decided it had enough. I replaced the timing belt kit. Started it up and what do you know bent valve in # 4 cylinder. What's the quickest cheapest fix? I'm thinking buy a used head. Also are heads off older Gen vw 2.0L all the same? Keep in mind I paid $900 for this car. So already not a lot invested and want to keep that way.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

I'm in no ways a VW expert, but it appears to me the cylinder head for your 2.0L (I believe is engine code: CCTA) is used through out a LOT of years of the 2.0L engines on VAG vehicles. My source is rather sketchy, but it seems it covers engines from 2006-2015.

Depends on how bad the damage is, you would have to remove the head to inspect it. Used head is a crapshoot, you don't typically remove a head if there was nothing wrong in there. A DIY resurface with glass and sandpaper can work as long as you're able to repair the valves.
